# � character in pages and post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

’(single inverdted comma) convert into �. If there is double space(in database) between 2 words then 1 space get convert into �. my database character set is already set to  utf8_general_ci. how can I remove it? I already searched for it but don't get it work.

Comment: where you see that malformed character?in the brower? in the cli?

Comment: it is in browser

Answer (score 0):

How are encode your files ? In most case, you should use UTF-8.

Comment: In what way is this an answer?